# Difference in differences with multiple time periods

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I am assessing the economic impact of High-Speed Rail (HSR) between two cities using Difference-in-Differences. To do so I have a set of treated and control regions (indexed by i). I am assuming that treatment starts at the year t=2007, and I have data from 2000 all the way to the year 2016. My query is as follows:

I am running a panel data regression using package 'plm' in R to quantify treatment effect through difference-in-differences. I have created year dummies for all my years (2000-2016), and my treatment starts at year 2007, yet when I run the regression it does not use year 2015 and 2016, hence regresses t-2 instead of t-1.

I am regressing the equation

$$Y_{it}=\beta_{0} + \beta_1 \cdot Group + \delta \cdot DID + \beta_2 \cdot \text{year_dummies} + \beta_3 \cdot X$$

Year dummies are: y2000, y2001, y2002, y2003, y2004,..., y2016. Group is a dummy with 1 for treated and 0 for control regions and Treat is a dummy with 1 for post-treatment(2007-2016) and 0 for pre-treatment (2000-2006)). However, when I run pooled OLS, fixed effects or first differences regressions, the model only regresses up to y2014, omitted the last two year dummies.

I would really appreciate if you could help me out to resolve the matter!

Comment: Obviously, your design matrix has col-linearity. The first column (for intercept) = Y2000+...,+Y2016. I think there is another collinearity. I have no data, so I cannot check it.  But first one is true. If you can give the definitions of Group, DID and X, maybe I can give you the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please further explain the fact that the design matrix has colinearity?
In terms of my regression equation: Yit, the dependent variable corresponds to GVA. Year dummies are: y2000, y2001, y2002, y2003, y2004,..., y2016. The DID term is an interaction between treated group and post-treatment time, DID=Group*Treat_time. X represents a set of explanatory variables such as ln(population), ln(employment), ln(average salary), etc.

Comment: Group is a dummy: maybe 0 for control, 1 for treated. What is treat_time?

Comment: Group is a dummy, 0 for control, 1 for treated. treat_time is a dummy, 1 for post-treatment (2007-2016) and 0 for pre-treatment (2000-2006)

Comment: Yit is regressed with ln, as: ln(Yit) which corresponds to GVA for each region at each year.

Comment: OK. I know what the problem is. I will write down.

Comment: Do you have Treat_time in the model?

Comment: I don't regress with Treat_time, as with the year dummies already present I think I would have collinearity

Comment: Then I could not find the second colinearity.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why the regressions use t-2 years

Comment: Only 2 cities' data?

Comment: I have data for several cities, some are part of the treated some part of the control group. I have been told to use the following code instead of year dummies but find strange results for the treatment effect:
is.factor(mydata$Year)    ; year.f=factor(mydata$Year)   ;  is.factor(year.f)  ;
    levels(year.f)

And then in my regression add the term +year.f

Comment: Your design matrix has 20 (betta0 + betta1Group + deltaDID + beta2(yeardummies)) + # of columns in your X. Could you do a regression analysis after the first column is excluded? Suppose X has 5 columns, then your design matrix has 25 columns.  After excluding the first column, you have 24 columns. You can use any of them as dependent variable and other 23 columns as independent variables. Then check the residuals and/or SSE. If colinearity exists, all of the residuals should be zero and SSE also should be zero.

Comment: @user163339 Not entirely sure what is going on. Can you run the OLS regression of Y on Group, Treat and DID, without the year dummies? Can you show us the R code?